# List of Lend Lease deliveries by years

Tags: united-states, world-war-two, soviet-union

Does someone know where I can find a list of the deliveries to the USSR by the "Lend Lease Act" of the United States 1941 to 1945 by year?

Most books like *"Russia's Life-Saver"* by Albert Weeks do have either a list by years in tonnage (not useful since no distinction is made between raw materials and war technology like tanks and aircraft) or a total list of all deliveries made 1941 to 1945 (again not useful because most of the deliveries were made 1944 and 1945).

Comment: You may be able to contact the National Archives for such a list. They do have [the logbooks of US Merchant Vessels](https://www.archives.gov/research/military/logbooks/merchant-vessels.html). However, Soviet Lend-Lease across the Pacific was carried by Soviet ships to avoid Japanese interdiction. Then there are the other two routes (Arctic Convoys and the Persian Corridor) which also may have used non-US ships.

Comment: What level of detail/granularity are you looking for? A general overview of how the different materials broke down over time (ie year X was mostly steel, year Y mostly tanks), or a detailed list on a year-by-year basis?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a list of tonnages by type and year (or rather by 'protocol period', July-June) [here](http://www.o5m6.de/Routes.html). It's very high-level, but it does at least let you show, for example, that food deliveries peaked in 1943-44 and dropped off the following year, replaced by railway equipment and petrol.

[Chart 6 here](https://www.ibiblio.org/hyperwar/USA/BigL/BigL-5.html) gives a rough year-by-year breakdown of numbers of aircraft, tanks, and other vehicles shipped in 1941-43, though sadly not after that. (It does suggest that the reports to Congress on lend-lease might have the specific numbers you're looking for)